# Angular PWA SwUpdate Snackbar

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I tried to implement a logic for my Angular PWA where a  [snackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview) gets triggert when an update is available and when the snackbar is dismissed I want a button to become available for the user to update the app manually. (the last thing is currently not implemented)

So far it worked out but the [checkForUpdate](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#checking-for-updates) is getting triggert over and over again ->  my console is getting spammed. I just can't figure out why this happens and what I understood wrong about the behavior of the [SwUpdate](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#swupdate-service)

I created a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-q4457d-hjfkf2?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts) where the problem is visible - I am getting an error that my browser is not supporting the service worker in stackblitz - any ideas how to fix that? (using chrome and the normal app running on localhost works fine)

app.component.ts:

```js
import { ApplicationRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { interval, concat } from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'newApp';
  updateAvailable = false;

  constructor(private snackbar: MatSnackBar, private swUpdate: SwUpdate, private appRef: ApplicationRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkUpdate();
  }

  openSnackbar() {
    const snack = this.snackbar.open('Update Available', 'Install Now!', { duration: 10000 });

    snack
      .onAction()
      .subscribe(() => {
        window.location.reload();
      });
    if(snack.afterDismissed()){
      console.log('afterDismissed: ', snack.afterDismissed())
      // here the button should become available for a manual update by the user
    } else {
      console.log('else: ', snack)
    }
  }

  checkUpdate() {
    //the Jquery stuff is from Angular-website so I guess it should work right?
    const appIsStable$ = this.appRef.isStable.pipe(
      first(isStable => isStable === true)
    );
    const everySixHours$ = interval(60000);
    const everySixHoursOnceAppIsStable$ = concat(appIsStable$, everySixHours$);

    everySixHoursOnceAppIsStable$.subscribe(() => {
      this.swUpdate.checkForUpdate().then(() => console.log('checked!'));
      if (this.swUpdate.available) {
        this.openSnackbar();
      } else {
        console.log('no update found!');
      }
      console.log('update checked!');
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add the htm to stackblitz

Comment: what html do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is within if:

```
  if (this.swUpdate.available) {
    this.openSnackbar();
  } else {
    console.log('no update found!');
  }
```

`this.swUpdate.available` is an observable which is always present. Proper usage would be to subscribe to it once:

```
this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => this.openSnackbar());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that propper and most recent solution (Angular 8 - 16) should look like this:

```js
const stableApp: Observable<boolean> = this.applicationRef.isStable.pipe(first(Boolean));
const everyHour: Observable<number> = timer(3 * 1000, 60 * 60 * 1000);

// Checks for an update on start and every hour and waits until the new version is downloaded from the server and ready for activation.
concat(stableApp, everyHour).subscribe(() => this.swUpdate.checkForUpdate());
    
// "versionUpdates" should be used instead of deprecated "available" observable.
this.swUpdate.versionUpdates.pipe(
    filter(($event: VersionEvent) => $event.type === 'VERSION_READY')
).subscribe(() => {
    // Update ready
    this.openSnackbar();
});
```